# TextInputLayout Render error with gradle 2.3.x

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I upgraded to Gradle 2.3.2 in my project using Android studio.  Prior to 2.3.x I had no issues.  The following xml segment used to work fine.  Now it fails in Render mode in Android studio.  It compiles and runs fine on my emulator and test devices, but I can not longer view the xml in preview.

### XML

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:transitionName="nodeNameTrans">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/nodeCustomName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_customname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

### XML ERROR

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat.clearColorFilter(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateEditTextBackground(TextInputLayout.java:897)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.drawableStateChanged(TextInputLayout.java:1392)
at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:17922)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15427)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

If I break the xml by removing the EditText the render seems to work, but it of course breaks my layout.

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
  applicationId "XX.XX.XX.XXXXXXXX"
  minSdkVersion 16
  targetSdkVersion 25
  versionCode 389
  versionName '1.6.610 '
  vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

  //jackOptions {
  //  enabled true
  //}
}

buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    debuggable false
    zipAlignEnabled true
    versionNameSuffix 'Release'
  }
  releaseDebug {
    //minifyEnabled true
    //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    //debuggable false
    //zipAlignEnabled true
    versionNameSuffix 'Beta'
    debuggable true
    jniDebuggable true
    minifyEnabled false
    zipAlignEnabled true
  }
  debug {
    //minifyEnabled false
    //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    debuggable true
    versionNameSuffix 'Beta'
  }
}

sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
externalNativeBuild {
  ndkBuild {
    path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
  }
 }
}

dependencies {
//compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//wearApp project(':wear')
compile ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2')
compile ('com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1')
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1')
compile ('com.android.support:design:25.3.1')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4')
compile project(':mstb')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Update your AppCompat/Support library.

Comment: I am already using the lastest versions:
---



  compile ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2')
  compile ('com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1')
  compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1')
  compile ('com.android.support:design:25.3.1')
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4')
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4')

Answer (score 0):

I had a dependency in my mstb lib that I moved to my main app project and it started working.

```
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.4')
```

Why this would have caused it, I have no idea.